# C# - Foreach list entry change webBrowser url and stop untill DocumentCompleted event was triggered

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to change the url of a `webBrowser` inside a C# winforms application for each user inside a list.

But once I've changed the url I want the browser go get the HTML content of a specified HTML class. So I've started to use the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1` event to grab this content once the browser finished loading the content of the profile.

But my `getUserContent` function is changing the url way to fast to let the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1` get the content. So it seems like the event is only triggered for the last user inside the list because its redirecting the urls to fast.

**Question:** Is there a way to stop my function `getUserContent` to redirect to the next url before the `webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1` event was triggered and run?

**Function to set the webBrowser to a new url:**

```
public void getUserContent()
{
    foreach (string username in usernames)
    {
        currentUser = username;
        webBrowser1.Url = new System.Uri("https://www.twitter.com/" + username, System.UriKind.Absolute);

    }
}
```

**webBrowser Document loaded event:**

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElementCollection divs = doc.GetElementsByTagName("div");

        string result = "";
        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "ProfileHeaderCard")
            {
                result = el.InnerText;
            }
        }

        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have more than one URL then you have multiple clients (HttmlRequest) so you should then have a list of clients.  So your Document Complete can test the URL to determine which client is responding.  You should be getting a different document complete for each browser.

Comment: So there's no way to use one browser then call the first url and wait for the Document Complete to get the data and continue with the next user?

Comment: You can use on browser but you would need to call the Create() method for each URL.  You would also have to wait for the response from each URL before calling the next URL.